# Data saved while testing Android app on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I debugged an app on android studio to test it, I entered some values inside the app.
But when I debugged it again I found that those values still exist in the app.
I cleaned and build again but did not work.
Can anyone help please? and thank you in advace :)

Comment: Cleaning just deletes the compiled sources and APK files on your computer; it doesn't do anything to the data on your phone. You can always just reset the app data on your phone the normal way.

Comment: Yeah, first time I faced this problem didn't know what to do :D thank you for your help @AndrewSun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the device, close the app using task manager before running it again.

Alternatively, uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: Thank you @Garrett